# Parametric equation problem calculus

Tags: calculus, parametric

A particle starts at the origin and moves along the curve $y = \dfrac{2x^{3/2}}{3}$ in the positive $x$-direction at a speed of $4$ cm/sec, where $x$ and $y$ are in measured in cm. Find the $x$-coordinate of the particle at $t = 5$.

I honestly have very limited ideas on how to approach this problem. I set $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 4$, to get $\int dx = \int 4dt$, and ultimately that $x = 4t + C$. But I haven't done anything with integrals with parametric equations before and I don't know how to continue. Could someone help me?

Comment: When $t=0$, the $x$-coordinate is $0$. So $C$ would be $0$?

Comment: So the equation for the x-coordinate is $x=4t$? So the answer would be $20$ right? But when I submit that it says it is incorrect for some reason..

Comment: Would *speed* here means $\sqrt{(x')^2 + (y')^2}$?

Comment: That is not right. The given velocity is along the curve, not the horizontal velocity. Actually $dx/dt$ is not a constant.

Comment: Note the shape of the curve. As $x$ changes, so does $y$, but they do so at different rates. Differentiate both sides with respect to $t$ to establish the relationship between these rates.

Comment: You know the value of $\sqrt{x’^2+y’^2}$. You need to use the chain rule to express $y’$ through $x’$.

Comment: Is it $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt}\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: That is Correct.

Comment: Ok but wait how does that help to find the x-coordinate of the particle at $t=5$?

Comment: You get a differential equation $\sqrt{1+x}\,dx=4dt$ easy to integrate because it is separable. Just integrate both sides from $0$ to $5$.

Comment: Umm I got $x = \left(\frac{1}{2} t + C\right)^2 - 1$?

Comment: Please check the ODE. There was a typo before. I edited it.

Comment: One more typo. Should be correct now.

Comment: I don’t think your formula is correct.

Comment: Me neither... after your updated hint I got $x = \frac{(4t+2)^2 - 4}{4}$ but I don't think that is right.

Comment: Let me check. .

Comment: When you integrate and use the initial condition you obtain $2(1+x)^{3/2}/3=4t+2/3$. Then just plug in $t=5$. I get $x=31\sqrt{31}-1$, which is ugly but probably correct.

Comment: Hmm.. that is incorrect

Comment: It is $x=31^{2/3}-1$.

Comment: Sorry I am doing it in my head..

Comment: Approx $8.86827…$ much less than $20$.

Comment: Oh thank you! That's really interesting

Answer (score 1):

If $f'(x)$ is continuous then the distance along the graph of $f$ from $(0,f(0))$ to $(p,f(p))$ is $$D(0,p)=\int_0^p (1+f'(x)^2)^{1/2}dx.$$   At $4$ cm/sec, after $5$ seconds we have $D(0,p)=20.$ We have $f'(x)=(2x^{3/2}/3)'=x^{1/2}.$ So we seek $p$ such that $$20=\int_0^p (1+x)^{1/2}dx.$$